# Ansible - Cisco NX-OS unable to determine device OS

Tags: ansible, cisco, ansible-inventory

I'm a newbie on Ansible and I am trying to extract some typical show output from Cisco Nexus devices using the Ansible [`cisco.nxos`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/nxos/index.html) modules.

I am using the `cisco.nxos.nxos_command` module within the playbook to run `show version` on the NX-OS devices. However, I am getting the following error upon playbook execution:

```
fatal: [Nx-01]: FAILED! =>
  msg: Unable to automatically determine host network os. Please manually configure ansible_network_os value for this host
```

However, I am specifying the OS type in the inventory file:

```
[nxos]
Nx-01

[nxos:vars]
ansible_connection=ansible.netcommon.network_cli
**ansible_network_os=cisco.nxos.nxos**
ansible_user=testuser
ansible_ssh_pass=test
```

Here is the playbook I am using:

```
---
- name: show version
  hosts: nxos
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: show version
      cisco.nxos.nxos_command:
        commands: show version
      register: output

    -  debug: var=output.stdout_lines
```

Am I missing something? The exact same setup works perfectly for Cisco IOS when used with `cisco.ios` module.